# Отправка на эмейл контента, div блока

Tags: php, отправка

Скачал скрипт отправки данных формы на эмейл (имя, эмейл, телефон и проч.). Хочу чтобы в письмо включался определенный div со всем контентом внутри него.

Сейчас это выглядит так:

```
$form['form-1'] = array(
'fields' => array(
    'name' => array(
        'title' => 'Имя:  ')
     'email' => array(
        'title' => 'Эмейл клиента:  ')
```

и т.д. 
HTML

```
    <form action="" method="get" name="form-1"> 
       <input name="name" type="text" placeholder="Ваше имя">
    </form>
```

Потом он с помощью

```
   $sb['body'] = "";
  // парсим шаблон
  if($form['cfg']['tpl']) {
   $out = tpl(array('name' => $act, 'getdata' => $getdata, 'cfg' => $form['cfg']));
   if(is_string($out)) {
      $sb['body'] = $out;
   }
 }
    $mail = mail($To, $sb['subject'], $sb['body'], $headers);
```

отравляет данные формы на эмейл (вроде как).

Шаблон выглядит так:

```
<table border="0" style="color:#333; padding: 20px;">
  <tr>
    <td>%%name.title%%</td>
    <td>%%name.value%%</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Нужно чтобы в письмо включались результаты некого расчета, который в конечном htmle выглядит так:

```
<div id="need">
<div id="length">
    <span>Длина : ></span><span class="received_data_from_js">95</span>
    <span>Стоимость: ></span><span class="received_data1_from_js">190</span>
</div>
```

Как такое сделать?

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте в шаблон ваш html

```
<table border="0" style="color:#333; padding: 20px;">
  <tr>
    <td>%%name.title%%</td>
    <td>%%name.value%%</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<div id="length">
    <span>Длина : ></span><span class="received_data_from_js">%%length%%</span>
    <span>Стоимость: ></span><span class="received_data1_from_js">%%cost%%</span>
</div>
```

и потом передайте параметры длины и стоимости в него

```
$sb['body'] = "";
  // парсим шаблон
if($form['cfg']['tpl']) {
   $out = tpl(['name' => $act, 'getdata' => $getdata, 'cfg' => $form['cfg'], 'length' => 'ЗНАЧЕНИЕ ДЛИНЫ', 'cost' => 'ЗНАЧЕНИЕ СТОИМОСТИ']);
     if(is_string($out)) {
        $sb['body'] = $out;
     }
   }
$mail = mail($To, $sb['subject'], $sb['body'], $headers);
```